# Getting ETF components (underlying stocks)

Tags: programming, etf

Using EDGAR's API interface, what is the best way to get the list of an ETFs underlying stock positions (in this case, just the CIKs)? I can pull all of the CIKs from EDGAR with no issue. Given that ETFs change their composition, I am looking to query this data monthly.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "where", you can scrape the info you need from SEC forms NPORT-P. they are monthly and contain the underlying positions of each ETF in Part C of the form. (see example here https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/36405/000175272421045740/xslFormNPORT-P_X01/primary_doc.xml)